# How can I set a counter column value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with a "SortID" column that is numbered using consecutive numbers. Whenever a row is deleted, it leaves a gap. Is there a way using pure SQL to update the rows with their row number? Something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET SortID={rowindex} ORDER BY SortID
```

(I realize this isn't valid SQL, that's why I'm asking for help)

This should set the first row to #1, the second row to #2... etc. Is this possible using SQL? Please forgive the poorly worded question, I'm not really sure the best way to ask this. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MySQL variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) can be used for this.

```
SET @a:=0;
UPDATE tbl SET sortId=@a:=@a+1 ORDER BY sortId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql user defined variables

```
SET @pos=0;
SELECT @pos:=@pos+1, * FROM tbl ORDER BY SortID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need it? Presentation layer is used for numbering most of time.

Comment: This is for storing the sort order for a list of items that is maintained by the user.

Comment: @Jon but  whenever a row is deleted, this "gap" wouldn't affect a sort order

Comment: Not necessarily on deleting, but on inserts it does affect the order. I usually number the rows counting by 2's, then I can insert a new row in the middle and update the sortID in the same transaction.