# MySQL - How to determine position ranking of table sorted by two columns and allowing for ties?

Tags: mysql

I have a table (tournament) that contains a list of teams and their accumulated points and goal difference (goals scored - goals conceded).

Tournament

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|   team    | points | goal_diff |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| USA       |      7 |   -2      |
| Brazil    |     12 |   +7      |
| Argentina |     12 |   +10     |
| Germany   |      7 |   -2      |
| Italy     |      3 |    0      |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

How do I rank them by points, and then by goal difference keeping ties with the same ranking and skipping the subsequent ranking position? I'm looking for the query to yield this end result:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+------+
|   team    | points | goal_diff | rank |
+-----------+--------+-----------+------+
| Argentina |     12 | +10       |    1 |
| Brazil    |     12 | +7        |    2 |
| USA       |      7 | -2        |    3 |
| Germany   |      7 | -2        |    3 |
| Italy     |      3 | 0         |    5 |
+-----------+--------+-----------+------+
```

I have been able to rank them and keep ties the same by the points column, but have no idea what to do to include the second column condition

```
SELECT s.team, s.points, s.goal_diff,
    (( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT points) FROM Tournament WHERE points > s.points ) + 1) AS rank
FROM Tournament s
ORDER BY s.points DESC
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add a counter column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527981/how-can-i-set-a-counter-column-value-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone trying to figure this out, I ended up upgrading my DB to MariaDB 10.3.14 and used the RANK() function which does exactly what I needed here.

Here's the code:

```
SELECT team, points, goal_diff,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY
            points DESC,
            goal_diff DESC
        ) rank
FROM Tournament;
```

I understand upgrading the DB may not be an option for everyone, but it was a very easy solution in my case.
Hope it is also helpful for others.

Comment: I really like this option. I'm fairly new to MariaDB and I'm glad there's a function like this. Good job!

Comment: FYI, the RANK() function and other window functions support starts with MariaDB 10.2. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/ for more info

Answer (score 1):

I missed : in #1(after @rank), that is the reason why show you blob and null value

```
SELECT
    a.team,
    a.points,
    a.goal_diff,
    a.rank 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        t.team,
        t.points,
        t.goal_diff,
    IF
        ( @points = t.points, 
        IF 
            (@goal_diff = t.goal_diff, @rank, @rank :=@inRank),
        @rank := @inRank ) AS rank,                               # 2
        @inRank := @inRank + 1,                                   # 3
        @points := t.points,                                      # 4
        @goal_diff := t.goal_diff  
    FROM
        `tournament` t,
        ( SELECT @points := NULL, @goal_diff := NULL, @rank := 0, @inRank := 1 ) b  # 1
    ORDER BY
    t.points DESC, t.goal_diff DESC
    ) a
```

**Explanation:**

**@** is used to declare a variable. **:=** means assign value to a variable.  #1 sql is actually a variable initial.

```
@points :  a custom declared variable for storing the points value in last row
@rank   :  a custom declared variable for storing regular condition rank number  
@inRank :  a custom declared variable for storing a count of row
```

**if(boolean, trueResult, falseResult)** function in mysql is kind of like a ternary operation. In #2, if the initial variable @points is equals to the value selected, it would show the value of @Rank which is 0 now. This if() function is used to judge if points values are the same.

After the if() function, we assign the variables in #3 and #4.

sql #3 increases in every row, this variable would count the row number. Thus, I can get the rank when points are not same. I think renaming @inRank to @increaseRank would be better.

sql #4 assigns the points value of this row to the variable. We use it to campare with the points value of next row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @wl.GIG


I put your code to test and I'm getting [BLOB - 1 B] and NULL values on the rank column. Unfortunately I don't understand what your code does =(
and I'm unable to try and get it fixed.

Could you please take a second look?

Comment: I did some modification on @wl.GIG code because on my initial testing it also shows  some NULL value. After I get it working, I noticed that one of the ranking is off. Instead of showing `1,2,3,3,5` it showed `1,1,3,3,5`.

Comment: I also want to repeat what @JuanCarlosLau said, this need an explanation because I also don't quite understand what the code does. Honestly, I myself haven't done anything like this before, not until yesterday. So, I made a brief research myself to understand it but I'm still curious of some operation in the query.

Comment: It worked well just try it second time, I will give you guys some explanation later.

Comment: @tcadidot0 Generally, edits that change the nature of a non-CW answer shouldn't be made. I really want to be able to mark [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22864959) as "disputed", but I can't, so I'm having to reject it. Sorry. You can write your own answer if you like!

Comment: @tcadidot0, could you share the changes you made?

Comment: I correct my error and update some explanation.@JuanCarlosLau, @tcadidot0

Comment: My bad @wizzwizz4 , I didn't know that. I just thought that I don't want to give an answer based on answer that is already been posted. It doesn't seem fair but if that's the rule, I will comply :)

Comment: As for the edits, I hope you don't mind @wl.GIG , I'm modifying your answer a little bit and post it here with explanation why I made the edit. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @tcadidot0 I did not see your modification

Comment: It was rejected. I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: I modified it for the goal_diff requirement. I think it is cool now @tcadidot0

Comment: Yes! It works now.. I like this better. Silly me, I didn't think about adding that `@goal_diff` variable. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, this is a minor edit from @wl.GIG answer. The result I get when running @wl.GIG is as below;

```
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------+
|    team     |  points  |  goal_diff  |  rank  |
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------+
|  Brazil     |      12  |          7  |     1  |
|  Argentina  |      12  |         10  |     1  |
|  USA        |       7  |         -2  |     3  |
|  Germany    |       7  |         -2  |     3  |
|  Italy      |       3  |          0  |     5  |
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

It's not giving the correct rank as OP's required but it's a very good approach and I'm very interested in it. So, I've made tests that can return the rank as per OP's requirement and here is what I come up with:

```
SELECT
    a.team,
    a.points,
    a.goal_diff,
    a.rank 
FROM (SELECT
        t.team,
        t.points,
        t.points+t.goal_diff AS tp, -- I've added this.
        t.goal_diff,
     IF
        (@points = t.points+t.goal_diff, --- changed this part.
        @rank, @rank := @inRank) AS rank,
        @inRank := @inRank + 1,
        @Points := t.points+t.goal_diff --- and changed this part.
    FROM
        `tournament` t,
        ( SELECT @points := NULL, @rank = 0, @inRank := 1 ) b 
        ORDER BY t.points DESC,t.goal_diff DESC 
        -- and added another condition in the ordering
        ) a;
```

As you can see, it wasn't a big edit but I with this, I get the result like below:

```
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------+
|    team     |  points  |  goal_diff  |  rank  |
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------+
|  Argentina  |      12  |         10  |     1  |
|  Brazil     |      12  |          7  |     2  |
|  USA        |       7  |         -2  |     3  |
|  Germany    |       7  |         -2  |     3  |
|  Italy      |       3  |          0  |     5  |
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

That's it.

Comment: Oh, I did not see the requirement of goal_diff. But there are two problems: 1.points+goal_diff would change the ranking rule, like points=11, goal_diff=12. It should be the third one in ranked table, and it would be first one now. 2. I think goal_diff should be treated as an absolute value

Comment: Forget the second one, lol.  I was confused to goal_diff. Now I figure it out.

Comment: Forget the second one, lol.  I was confused to goal_diff. Now I figure it out.